# Imprecision when passing from string to int character by character in c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, int, character

First of all I am taking the string from geline(cin, s) and the input is in the form of: **100 49**. And I can not take it with normal cin because I need to know where geline(cin, s) makes s empty so that means is a blank line and I should stop the program.
When passing from string '99' (or any other number below 100) to int 99 there is no problem. But when I try a number greater than 99 it gave the (number - 1). Also I found that this happens with numbers below 1000 but from 1000 to 10000 it is ok, but  I tested number greater than 10^4 and it gave the (number - 1) another time.
Here is my code to convert the string

```
//Search how many nums are in the string wer are passing until an space or new line

int nums = 0;

for(int j = i; j < s.size(); j++){
  if(s[j] == ' ' || s[j] == '\n') break;
  nums++;
 }

 //pass to the variable time the string character by character
 int time = 0;

 while(nums--){
    time += (s[i] - '0') * (pow(10, nums));
    i++;
}
```

I would like to know if there is an error from my computer or I am missing something.

Comment: Off-topic, but I bet there is no need to use a floating point function such as `pow` in whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve], you are missing huge part of your code

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie pow could be the reason for this strange behaviour ?

Comment: Look up atoi().

Comment: "pow could be the reason for this strange behaviour ?" most probably not, at least not directly. But using 2 loops and `pow()` is inefficeint and convoluted way. One loop would be enough.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a std::string to int? Do you know std::stoi?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I have looked for atoi and stoi but I need to take multiple inputs with getline(), and this is why I am doing that.

Comment: Why not `std::cin >> time`? `need to take multiple inputs` Is this somewhat relevant to `stoi`?

Comment: @KamilCuk because the input is of the form 100 4  and ther are several inputs and i need to know where is a blank line to do something else and then restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all I am taking the string from geline(cin, s) and the input is in the form of: 100 49.

Then simplest solution is to use `std::istringstream`:

```
int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
std::istringstream( s ) >> i1 >> i2;
```